# Android inapp purchase validation issue : Can't resolve code, return value is always zero

Tags: php, android, openssl, in-app-purchase

I'm using openssl_verify() method to validate INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA and SIGNATURE using the public key from Google Developer Console.

I'm parsing the data and signature from my app to a url on which the following php code is running. While I make a test purchase from my android app, my script runs fine, however the return value is always zero.

Can anyone tell what is wrong with the code?

Is there an issue with the formats of the above two fields?

Also can anybody suggest a better way to parse the parameters to my php script?

## Here's the code I'm using

```
<?php 

$signed_data = $_REQUEST["signed_data"];
$signature = $_REQUEST["signature"];
$public_key_base64 = "......";

function verify_market_in_app($signed_data, $signature, $public_key_base64) 
{

    $key =  "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n".
        chunk_split($public_key_base64, 64,"\n").
        '-----END PUBLIC KEY-----';   
    //using PHP to create an RSA key
    $key = openssl_get_publickey($key);
    
    //$signature should be in binary format, but it comes as BASE64. 
    //So, I'll convert it.
    $signature = base64_decode($signature);   
    
    //using PHP's native support to verify the signature
    
    $result = openssl_verify(
            $signed_data,
            $signature,
            $key,
            OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA1);

    echo $result;
    if (0 === $result) 
    {
        echo "false";
        return false;
    }
    else if (1 !== $result)
    {
        echo "false";
        return false;
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "true";
        return true;
    }
    
} 

verify_market_in_app($signed_data, $signature, $public_key_base64);

?>
```